# Secure TCP communication between non-named machines?

Tags: security, node.js, encryption, tcp

Given a bunch of machines who are on the network and who shall talk to each other using TCP.

My demands are:

- Data must be encrypted.
- Data must not be sent to an unauthorized machine even if it is on the same network.
- Data must not be received from an unauthorized machine.
- Machines know only the IP addresses of the other machines.

For a better imagination, think of a chat network where only authorized clients are allowed to participate, and all communication shall be encrypted.

My initial idea was to use a TLS certificate:

- Each authorized machine has a copy of that certificate.
- Using the certificate the connection can be encrypted.
- Using the certificate on the server side it can be used to verify the server.
- Using the certificate on the client side it can be used to authenticate a client.
- As unauthorized machines do not have the certificate, they can neither decrypt, send nor receive data.

In theory, this should work out as expected.
In practices, it doesn't.

One of the problems is that the machines only know each other's IP address, and that they need not be bound to a domain name. As certificates are not recommended for IP addresses (and Node.js won't even validate a certificate with an IP address as CN), and the IP addresses may even change over time, I started to think whether that's the correct approach.

Of course, I could start implementing all this by myself: An encryption layer, an authentication schema, ... but I don't run after that. If there's a more convenient way of solving this, I'd appreciate this.

So, basically it comes down to use an TLS certificate for encryption and authentication, not because of the binding to a domain name, but because a specific certificate is present.

How would I implement this and solve the above mentioned issues?
Or - am I running in a completely wrong direction? How might I solve this in a better way?

Comment: Are these one a private network or are the IPs public? If so, why can't you use their domain name?

Comment: They are public, but we are talking about consumers as users. So the "usual" home PC which is online. They for sure do not have a stable domain name ;-). The only thing I can use (at least for a while) is the machine's IP address. And this is what differs in my scenario from the usual client-server scenario: I don't care WHO the participant is as long as he / she has the right certificate.

Comment: Then why don't you use the users account-name or email-address as the name of the certificate?

Comment: Because Node.js expects the certificate's CN to be the hostname (or, if the hostname is an IP address as in my case, Node.js expects the certificate to have a SAN with the IP address). But I do not care about the IP address ;-). Basically, I'd need a wildcard certificate for *any* IP address, and this - somehow - feels wrong ;-)

Comment: First and foremost you need to think of how you could authenticate your peer, independent of any TLS considerations. If the IP address can change and the machines are not named then how would you do it?

Comment: Existence of the certificate? Which means: I expect a another machine to be able to identify using a specific certificate. If it can, fine. If not, not fine ;-).

Comment: @Golo: What's stopping someone from reading the certificate from the network, and then replaying it to you later? A certificate isn't encrypted in TLS. A certificate validates the security of the tunnel -- it doesn't serve as an authentication mechanism.

Comment: Does it really not solve as an authentication mechanism? I though that client-side certificates are made exactly for this, am I wrong about this?

Comment: You are confusing client-side certs and server certs.  A server cert should (generally) be bound to the hostname; a client certificate can have any subject you want.